# Getting correct element from a array in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Below is a method in `OnClickListner`. I want to pass first `1=0`, then `i=1` likewise.

But below code shows only `i=0`;

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(i=0; i<shopTelNos.length;i++){
                    Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(),"value is : "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Help me on this.

Comment: why there is a break; ? Give some delay in your for loop. Otherwise you will not be able to see the Toasts. As for loop will execute faster than Toast display time

Comment: what is your shoptel array length, even if its 2, it will loop only once. coz yur condition is less than.

Comment: @tenten Remove break; statement and try

Comment: @Raghavendra I tried but that increments the `i`

Comment: I'm little confused clarify me please. Without incrementing how you will get i value 1 its always 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

I think the break is causing to stop after the first iteration on the loop. Try to remove the break and retest. it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure shopTelNos.length is more than 1? The for loop you have made loops through all the elements in the shopTelNoss array. If there is only one element in that array, it will only display the message once.

Answer (score 0):

First, either debug or print and check the array and its length to confirm its contents:

```
Log.i("ShopTel", "Array :" +shopTelNos);
Log.i("ShopTel", "Array size :" +shopTelNos.length);
```

Second, put a delay in between the toasts. The toasts may be overlapping.